# CodeIgniter - How to automatically remove a database value after specific amount of time?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've built a small login and authentication module using CodeIgniter, which allows for forgotten password reset.  The reset sends an email with a url and adds a random generated value to a forgotten_password column in the database to the supposed user who has forgotten  their password.  The email sent provides a link to a page for password reset that has the randomly generated value for verification with the database as segment(3).  I can remove this value once they submit a new password, but I want to remove it after 1-2 hours so it won't be valid anymore to reset the users password.  I'm not sure how to do this?  I thought maybe a cronjob, but all they mention is using the CLI to perform cronjobs.

How would I go about performing a timed task using CodeIgniter?

Comment: I recently wrote something similar and my solution was to include a timestamp in the table and use the business logic to determine whether or not the URL was valid based on elapsed time. Can you do the same?

Comment: Why the downvote?  I've done research. I've been using CodeIgniter for 5 days, using their documentation, which is great, but I had no idea how to implement a solution.

Comment: @MichaelO'Brien Thanks, that's a great alternative solution.  I hadn't thought of that.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With MySQL

Assuming you use MySQL database, there is a way for deleting rows after a short time. You can create a new MySQL database event of type `RECURRING` with no end date, where you simply put

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `expiryTime`-UNIX_TIMESTAMP() < 1
```

You need to enable event_scheduler then add a code something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT test
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `expiryTime`-UNIX_TIMESTAMP() < 1
```

Comparison expression may vary due to different methods of dates saving. In this case the field `expiryTime` would be saved as a `unix timestamp` to the time of expiry.

### With CRON

SSH command: `crontab -e`

Add this line:

```
0,30 * * * * php /path/to/script.php
```

in script.php write a code to look rows with >= 120 mins and delete them.

### With PHP and CRON

Add a column `date_added timestamp` to your table. This value is automatically set when you insert the row.

Then write a PHP script which executes this query `DELETE FROM [mytable] WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) > 7200`. Schedule a cron job to run this every minute or so.

Hope that helps

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic.  Great solutions!  Thanks for the thorough explanation, and the variations. Do you have a preference?  For example, I am using MySQL, so I could avoid the overhead of a cron job by using the first solution. Cheers

Comment: That from a bit of reading it looks like I need confirm my host has event_scheduler=on to use the first solution?

Comment: @mtpultz yes you have to turn on event_scheduler, and create an event in that table you created for this - I updated my answer above

Comment: @mtpultz also check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Comment: Thanks! This was a great help :)